# Why is isolation level ignored when using TransactionScopeOption.Suppress in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactionscope, isolation-level

I'm trying to execute an query with the isolation level read uncommitted within an existing transaction using LINQ TO SQL. If I use the option to suppress this transaction from the parent transaction, it seems I lose the ability to specify the isolation level. Using this code in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
var db = this;
db.ExecuteQuery<string>(@"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE");

using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    // updates or inserts here

    using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress,
        new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
    {
        db.ExecuteQuery<string>(@"SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncomitted' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Readcomitted' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
        where session_id = @@SPID
        ").Dump("Inside the transaction");

    }
    // updates or inserts here
}
}
```

I get the result of SERIALIZABLE. Is there any way to run a query inside a transaction and change the isolation level to read uncommitted?

Comment: One solution I've come across is to use literal sql to change the isolation level:

    using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
db.ExecuteQuery<string>(@"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");
......
    }

But I believe this would change the connection isolation level and not restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`. The `Supress` option causes your enclosing block to run without an ambient transaction and also without creating a new one. That's what it does.

`RequiresNew` causes a new, root transaction scope to be created.

See the summary table in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y1642) on how different options behave.

More on `Suppress`:

> **Suppress** is useful when you want to preserve the operations performed
>   by the code section, and do not want to abort the ambient transaction
>   if the operations fail. For example, when you want to perform logging
>   or audit operations, or when you want to publish events to subscribers
>   regardless of whether your ambient transaction commits or aborts.

Comment: I concede that your solution works, but I'm not sure why a transaction is required to set an isolation level. Whether you're in a transaction or not, the connection behaves with a given isolation level, so why can't you change it?